# What RAD tools are out there for GUI building in Perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, rad

I need to do some quick-and-dirty Perl GUI building. I can't afford a Komodo License.
What would people recommend as a free (as in beer) alternative. I don't care if it is UNIX or Windows or both. I would be using either Win32 Perl or Perl/Tk depending on what has the best solution. I would also look at any PM's that use something else.

Comment: Not enough information.  Perl doesn't have a gui API (ie, stock perl) which graphics/windowing SPI are you building against?  Tk? wxperl? etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Perl/Tk, there is [ZooZ](http://www.perltk.org/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=28&Itemid=29).

Personally, I prefer to use [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) for the GUI design and [Gtk2::GladeXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-GladeXML).  And as other people mentioned, there's also WxWidget and Qt alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

The Perlmonks post http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=627282 might help, as well as the google search for ["perl gui builder"](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en-us&q=perl+gui+builder&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). Once you see what's available, you might be able to ask a more specific question to get a better answer.

Good luck, :)